# Using Python to read / capture specific text of a secured google document (e.g. google slide) with log-in

Tags: html, forms, url, open-source

I want to capture the version history of a google slide but this google document needs log in using your gmail account.

I was trying to us use cookiejar and browser to fill in form name, username, password, etc.

However, I am struggling to find out the form name and name of the inputs of the form to fill for this google doc.

I've used Ctrl + U to try to find the code but in vain. Am not very familiar with html anyone can provide some ideas / reference / guidance? Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, isn't Google's own apis an option?

Comment: also, for a full reference on HTML, see [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) on it.